# How is "spoiler" possible in "The Wolverine"?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, the-wolverine

> Why is Yashida becoming younger when acquiring Wolverine's powers?

In the X-Men and Wolverine  movies the hero in question grows from a little boy to an adult as we see him in the latest movie *The Wolverine*.

> So what happens to Yashida does not follow that logic. Is that one of those goofs that film-makers do ?

Comment: Logic fails at various points during *The Wolverine*.

Comment: It's important to realize that the movie universes are separate from the comic universes. Powers and their limits are not necessarily the same between the two. While there is evidence that Wolverine will eventually die in the comics (which that question was about), there is no concrete evidence that he will in the movie universe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the movie, his power does appear to prevent aging.

In fact, it seems to be a pretty central theme to the movie.  Yashida explicitly states that what he is offering Logan is an end to his "eternal" existence"

> "I can end your eternity.  Make you mortal."

He's quite clear that he's offering to allow Logan to grow old, and die of a "normal" death.

Wolverine has not aged at all since he first met Yashida in World War II. It can be assumed from the ending that this "immortality" is achieved by his mutant healing factor "healing" the aging.

As noted in the comments above, this is not necessarily consistent with the comic book universe(s), but the repeated discussion of Wolverine's immortality, and the possibility that he will (or has) run out of things to live for, makes it pretty clear that, as far as the movie is concerned:

> Yes, it makes a kind of sense (as much as anything in the movie does) for Yashida to "heal" his old age.

Comment: As this is the closest to what I'm looking for....

Comment: Wouldn't it heal back to unbirth then? It definitely shouldn't work that way. There were a lot of things that bothered me about this movie.

Comment: @Rob The problems associated with aging are generally the results of the body losing its ability to heal or replace damaged or dead tissue.  So no, his age wouldn't be "healed" to "unbirth"... it would just regress until about the age of peak health.

Comment: I guess. It's still something I don't agree with, but I do understand what you mean!

Comment: Now make that work to fit with *Logan*. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

It actually does make sense. Growing and Aging are not exactly the same thing.
We do not yet know what actually causes biological aging. There are many different theories in that regard. But Aging in a biological sense is basically that the body can no longer regenerate it's cells properly. Our maintenance can no longer keep up with the wear and tear on our body. Because of this our body eventually fails to function.

If we assume that part of Wolverines healing factor is perfect cellular regeneration, then he is indeed immortal. He would still grow up because the process of growing up and the process of aging are separate. Once he's "fully" grown his body would switch from creating new cells to grow and regenerate to only creating cells for regeneration, replacing dead and damaged cells. He would not age in a biological sense.

So what happens if someone old acquires his healing ability? His body suddenly gains the ability to replace every single old and damaged cell with a perfectly new cell. He would return to a youthful yet fully grown individual at peak health.

The problem with the movie is that they made it look like a transfer of youth which doesn't make sense. If his cells already regenerated, Yashida should not have gone back to old age once Logan was free of him. And Logan shouldn't have looked like age was catching up with him. They explicitly said in the movie that he would live a normal lifespan and die of old age if he transferred his power (though this might have been a lie).

Aside from that it makes as much sense as a mutant with a super healing ability can in my opinion.

I'm always wondering where he keeps all that material needed to reproduce so many cells at once or if they are made automagically out of thin air.

Comment: In this sense then "aging" is a disease... Hmmm Kinda reminds me of a movie I once saw. _Life as a sexually transmitted disease_ for those who wonder what movie I'm talking about...